# How to get the number of days of current/last year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to find out the number of days from current and last year. I have managed to come up with this code which will give me a starting and ending date.

Then I use `NSDateComponents` to get the number of days for this current year. But what I get is `365`, which means is the number of days from last year.

How can I corectly get the number of days for last and current year ?

```
 func numOfDaysInYear() {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var interval = NSTimeInterval(0)
        var startOfYear: NSDate?
        var endOfYear: NSDate!
        calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Year, startDate: &startOfYear, interval: &interval, forDate: NSDate())
        endOfYear = startOfYear?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval - 1)


        let comp = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: startOfYear!, toDate: endOfYear, options: .MatchFirst)
        print(comp.day)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 endOfYear = startOfYear?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval - 1)
```

gives a date *within* the current year, and its difference to
`startOfYear` is 365 days, 23 hours and 59 seconds, and therefore the result is 365.

What you want is

```
let startOfNextYear = startOfYear!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
let comp = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: startOfYear!, toDate: startOfNextYear, options: .MatchFirst)
print(comp.day)
```

which gives the correct output `366` for the leap year 2016.

To get results for the previous year, just replace the current data
`NSDate()` by a date "one year ago":

```
calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.month = 1
let nextFirstJanuar = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingComponents: components, options: .MatchNextTime)!
let thisFirstJanuar = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(nextFirstJanuar, matchingComponents: components, options: [.MatchNextTime, .SearchBackwards])!
let lastFirstJanuar = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(thisFirstJanuar, matchingComponents: components, options: [.MatchNextTime, .SearchBackwards])!

let daysInThisYear = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: thisFirstJanuar, toDate: nextFirstJanuar, options: []).day
let daysInLastYear = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: lastFirstJanuar, toDate: thisFirstJanuar, options: []).day
```